# node to transver can't be null: Hibernate query giving java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: hibernate

i am trying to update record of my table but when i run the code i got this error 
Hibernate query giving java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 please help to fix this problem 
here is the code

```
public void forwardTo(File ob, Person selectedP)
    {

        try {
            //String queryString = "from File ";
            System.out.println("in dao");
            System.out.println(ob.getFileRefNo());
            String queryString = "update File f set f.createdPerson="+selectedP.getLogin()+"f.person="+selectedP.getPersonId()+ "where f.fileId="+ob.getFileId();
            System.out.println("after update query");
            Query queryObject = getSession().createQuery(queryString);
            getSession().merge(ob);
            System.out.println("after merge");
            int result=queryObject.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Rows affected="+result);
            log.debug("save successful");


        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("find all failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
```

here is the error log... which comes on the update of the foreign key

```
Nov 28, 2014 12:27:23 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.model.um.Person.personId
javax.el.ELException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.model.um.Person.personId
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:291)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.model.um.Person.personId
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3605)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3321)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:430)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:283)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1169)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:117)
    at com.dao.filling.FileDAO.forwardTo(FileDAO.java:284)
    at com.service.filling.FillingDataManager.forawrdTo(FillingDataManager.java:141)
    at com.controller.Controller.forwardTo(Controller.java:179)
    at com.managedBean.Filling.FileMB.forward(FileMB.java:275)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@13aebc8
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor88.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:169)
    ... 49 more

Nov 28, 2014 12:27:23 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
SEVERE: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.model.um.Person.personId
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3605)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3321)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:430)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:283)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1169)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:117)
    at com.dao.filling.FileDAO.forwardTo(FileDAO.java:284)
    at com.service.filling.FillingDataManager.forawrdTo(FillingDataManager.java:141)
    at com.controller.Controller.forwardTo(Controller.java:179)
    at com.managedBean.Filling.FileMB.forward(FileMB.java:275)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@13aebc8
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor88.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:169)
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: please post the error log so as easy to identify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a comma between your set's:

```
String queryString = "update File f set row1 = :row1Parameter, row2 = :row2Parameter where row3 = :row3Parameter";
```

The :parameters are called host variables and need to be declared outside of the statement, for example:

```
Query queryObject = getSession().createQuery(queryString);
queryString = "update File f set f.createdPerson = :createdPerson where ...";
queryObject.setParameter("createdPerson", selectedP.getLogin());
int rowsAffected = query.executeUpdate();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i made these changes and it works fine for the attributes "created person" and "fileId" but it gives error when i update the "person" attribute of the file table which is the foreign key... org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.model.um.Person.personId
javax.el.ELException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.model.um.Person.personId

Comment: in m using navicat and i have "cascade" value on update property but after getting this error i change the on update property from "cascade" to "no action" but the error remains same... what should i do to update foreign key in the "File" table...\\

Comment: try to set the personObject itself, not the ID, like queryObject.setParameter("person", selectedP); Hibernate will understand that this is a foreign key (because of your mapping) and does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String queryString = "update File f set f.createdPerson=" + selectedP.getLogin() + ",f.person=" + selectedP.getPersonId() + " where f.fileId=" + ob.getFileId();
```

I suggest you to execute with the following code. Your sql statement was missing a comma between the fields and a space before the where.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Transactional` annotation and you need a comma between your set's:

**Code**

```
@Override
@Transactional
public AppUser updateUserToken(AppUser user) {
    try {
        Query query=em.createQuery("update AppUser as u set u.token=:token , u.updatedDate=:updatedDate where u.id=:userId").setParameter("userId", user.getId()).setParameter("token", user.getToken()).setParameter("updatedDate", user.getUpdatedDate());
        query.executeUpdate();
        return user;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```